# UICollectionView items spacing is not constant

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to show a collection view with each cell displaying a string inside border. I have set the direction to VERTICAL. So there can be multiple cells in each row with dynamic size. But cells are being displayed with different inter items space.

Current State of Collection View:

[image]

My collection view configuration is below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if(collectionView == tagsCollectionView)
    {
        if(self.propertyTypes.count > 0)
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                return CGSize(width: "You searched for properties in: ".width(withConstrainedHeight: 25, font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 13)!), height: 30)
            }
            return CGSize(width: self.propertyTypes[indexPath.row - 1].width(withConstrainedHeight: 25, font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 13)!), height: 30)
        }
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    return "String".size(withAttributes: nil)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

**However, the collection view works absolutely fine when the direction is HORIZONTAL.**

Comment: try using this collectionview flowlayout class to get rid of this calculation:- https://github.com/Digipolitan/collection-view-left-align-flow-layout

Comment: That's the behavior of the default layout. It's like "Justified text". fit line width, except last line. You need a custom layout to achieve what you want.

Comment: try to put code in didLoad():- ```yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = DGCollectionViewLeftAlignFlowLayout()```

Comment: yea got it @KishanBarmawala.

Comment: @KishanBarmawala Thanks bro! you made my day! Cheers

Comment: haha, then upvote please. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pod: https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout to achieve your functionality.

You can achieve left, right, justified etc. with this library.

Use it like:

```
let alignedFlowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout
alignedFlowLayout?.horizontalAlignment = .left
alignedFlowLayout?.verticalAlignment = .top
```

Check library for more detailed info.